# Maximise $\sum_{x,y\in S} GCD(x,y)$ where $S = \{1,2,\ldots, 100\}$ and each number appears once in the sum

Tags: elementary-number-theory, optimization, gcd-and-lcm, matching-theory

**Question:** One day Anindya and his friend Faria cooperated to play a fun game. They played to maximize the sum of points they gained throughout the game.

Let $S = \{1,2,\ldots, 100\}$. There are $50$ rounds. In each round of the game, they will decide together to choose two distinct numbers $x,y$ from $S$ such that neither $x$ nor $y$ have been chosen in previous rounds. Let's say Faria's number is $x$ and Anindya's number is $y$. They will then gain $GCD(x,y)$ points, where GCD is the Greatest Common Divisor function.

Find the total (maximized) number of points that they gained in the game.

**My solution:**
My way to achieve this is to choose consecutive pairs of numbers. For example:

Round $1$:
Anindya: $1$
Faria: $2$
$GCD(1, 2) = 1$

Round $2$:
Anindya: $3$
Faria: $4$
$GCD(3, 4) = 1$

...

Round $49$:
Anindya: $97$
Faria: $98$
$GCD(97, 98) = 1$

Round $50$:
Anindya: $99$
Faria: $100$
$GCD(99, 100) = 1$

In each round, the GCD is $1$, and they gain $1$ point. Therefore, in $50$ rounds, they will gain a total of $50$ points.

But when I did some brute force calculation , I was stuck . If we choose round $50$  $(100 , 50 )$ and round $49$ $( 49 , 98 )$ , the total sum will be greater than my previous answer sum .

So what will be actual procedure to solve this problem?

Comment: Let us consider (1,2) ; (2,4); ( 4,8) ; (8;16) ;( 16; 32) ; (32, 64) ;(64 96);(96;100) And now we have 1+2+4+8+16+32+64+32+4=163 points. I have to think about proof of optimalization, but great clue is fact 
$ gcd(a,b) \leq min \{a;b \} $

Comment: Some food for thought: 1/ What is the maximum number of times that they can score 50?   2/ What is the maximum number of times that they can score 49?   3/ What is the maximum number of times that they can score 25? What if you knew that they scored 50?   4/ What is the maximum number of times that they can score 16? What if they optimized their gameplay? 5/ What is the maximum number of times that they can score 15? What if they optimized their gameplay?

Comment: @AdamWrzesiński sir none of them can choose one number in more than one round .

Comment: I see no reason to think that having them choose consecutive numbers will maximize the number of points.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this as a [maximum weight matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_weight_matching) problem in a complete graph with node set $\{1,\dots,100\}$ and edge weight $\gcd(i,j)$.  The maximum turns out to be $1187$, attained for example by

```
(1,89),(2,4),(3,93),(5,85),(6,9),(7,77),(8,16),(10,20),(11,55),(12,24),(13,65),(14,91),(15,95),(17,51),(18,54),(19,57),(21,63),(22,66),(23,69),(25,75),(26,52),(27,81),(28,56),(29,58),(30,60),(31,62),(32,64),(33,99),(34,68),(35,70),(36,72),(37,74),(38,76),(39,78),(40,80),(41,82),(42,84),(43,86),(44,88),(45,90),(46,92),(47,94),(48,96),(49,98),(50,100),(53,73),(59,71),(61,97),(67,79),(83,87)
```